# An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue

Tags: sql, sql-server, broker

When I execute the following query on my SQL database:

```
USE DATABASENAME
GO

SELECT transmission_status, * 
FROM sys.transmission_queue
GO
```

I get the following error message:

> An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15404, State: 19. Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'Domain\User', error code 0x5.

When it comes to the SQL Server Broker services, is it possible that the error is due to the fact we're trying to use a Windows NT/Network Authenticated account? Would using SQL Authenticated account eliminate this error?

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Possible solution](http://serverfault.com/questions/277551/mssqlserver-exception-occurred-while-enqueueing-a-message-in-the-target-queue-e)

Comment: Hi lad2025,

Thank you for the suggestion! I guess another part to my question, would be, what would the best practice be, for configuring and implementing SQL Server Broker services for an application that runs off of web services? The suggestion references SharePoint. Grant, the error is the same, this is not directly associated to SharePoint.

-Steve

Comment: You should really ask this question about best practices [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), here it is off-topic.